# How to get bash completion settings to be inherited by child shells?

Tags: bash, environment-variables, autocomplete

I have a project-specific setup file that I source right before running gnu screen.

In that file, I set up bash completion for my test command and the related tests.

That looks like this:

```
$PROJECT_HOME/app/bin/lib/behat_suites.sh  # _behat_suites() defined here
complete -F _behat_suites run_behat_suite
export -f _behat_suites
```

Problem is, each screen is a new shell, and the `complete -F` setting doesn't survive (rest of then environment does - they're proper subshells).

The `export` means the function survives into the screen sub-shells, but the completion setting itself doesn't.

Short of a tool like direnv, or putting the setting in my user ~/.bashrc, is there a way to get the completion setting to be inherited by the child shell processes?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any method for doing this, easily. You'd have to pass the output of `complete -p` from the parent shell to the child shells.

To start this allows for you to inject extra commands to the subshell:

```
$ bash --rcfile <(echo '. ~/.bash_profile')
```

Now if we try and introduce `complete -p` to this, like so:

```
$ bash --rcfile <(echo '. ~/.bash_profile'; while read line; do echo "$line"; done < <(complete -p))
complete: usage: complete [-abcdefgjksuv] [-pr] [-DE] [-o option] [-A action] [-G globpat] [-W wordlist]  [-F function] [-C command] [-X filterpat] [-P prefix] [-S suffix] [name ...]
```

It almost works, it appears to be getting tripped up on the `complete` commands coming in. Trying to use a file as the intermediate didn't work either:

```
$ complete -p > /tmp/cmp.txt; bash --rcfile <(echo '. ~/.bash_profile'; echo '. /tmp/cmp.txt')
complete: usage: complete [-abcdefgjksuv] [-pr] [-DE] [-o option] [-A action] [-G globpat] [-W wordlist]  [-F function] [-C command] [-X filterpat] [-P prefix] [-S suffix] [name ...]
```

Trying to see why it's failing doesn't really shed much additional light on things. Here I'm enabling verbose output from bash via the `-set -x`:

```
$ bash
$ set -x
```

We then source the file we made a second ago:

```
$ . /tmp/cmp.txt
+ . /tmp/cmp.txt
++ complete -F _manila manila
++ complete -F _minimal
complete: usage: complete [-abcdefgjksuv] [-pr] [-DE] [-o option] [-A action] [-G globpat] [-W wordlist]  [-F function] [-C command] [-X filterpat] [-P prefix] [-S suffix] [name ...]
++ complete -F _command time
++ complete -F _command do
++ complete -o bashdefault -o default -o nospace -F __git_wrap_git_checkout gcob
```

So unless there's some cleverness, it looks like the data contained within the output of `complete -p` is not portable in this particular case.

#### References

- [How to invoke bash, run commands inside the new shell, and then give control back to user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120426/how-to-invoke-bash-run-commands-inside-the-new-shell-and-then-give-control-bac)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to put *all* of the settings in your ~/.bashrc, but you could add a "one-liner" that sees if the `_behat_suites` function has been defined *and* 
the completion function has *not* been defined; if so, then define the completion.

Here's the one-liner, broken up a bit for readability:

```
declare -f _behat_suites          >/dev/null && 
  ! complete -p run_behat_suite   >/dev/null && 
      complete -F _behat_suites run_behat_suite
```